# how to correct the title bar's appearance of the eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, titlebar

I am recently bored with the problem of the eclipse IDE.

No matter which project I am in currently, the title bar always shows "MapViewer-newnewnew", which once was some other project of mine. Although the problem is not such technical, it bothers me a lot.... could someone help me with this?

See the image below

[image: Wrong title bar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of the window title is the workspace name if set - see `IDEWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.computeTitle()`. See preferences -> "Workspace" for the current name.

If not set, it is the perspective name in which case I guess you have a perspective with the name "MapViewer-newnewnew". Check in "Customize Perspective..."

Comment: eh..thank you for your answer, but as you can see from the titlebar in the image, it is in "Java" perspective... and I'm sure the name of "MapViewer ...." is a project which I built previously.

Comment: just now I found that it was because I used the "Open in new window" popup menu on that project. now what puzzles me is how can I restore this to default? because once I open a project in a new window , it seems that the title of the IDE change to that name permanently.....                            by the way , how can I enter the "new line" character in this "Add Comment" textarea? why it just submit the comment once i pressed the Enter key?

Comment: @user1150712 For the last part, have a look at the meta site: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/165688

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I fixed it by first choosing 'Window' -> 'Close All Perspectives' and then 'Window' -> 'Open Perspective' and choosing the perspective I wanted.  The fixed project in the title bar disappeared.